# Writing to .plist returns "Success!" but ends up blank

Tags: objective-c, plist, writetofile

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)btnSaveInfo:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *appInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: fieldAPI.text, @"App API", fieldID.text, @"App ID", fieldName.text, @"App Name", nil];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *newPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppData.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *appdata = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:newPath];
    [appdata addObject:appInfo];
    NSLog(@"%@",appdata);
    [appdata writeToFile:newPath atomically:YES];

    if ([data writeToFile:newPath atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
        NSMutableArray *finalData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:newPath];
        NSLog(@"Final array:\n\n%@",finalData);
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error...");
    }
    [data release];
    }
```

My NSLogs return

```
2012-12-23 01:20:37.628 Parse Push[38052:c07] (
        {
        "App API" = asdf;
        "App ID" = adsf;
        "App Name" = asdf;
    }
)
2012-12-23 01:20:37.932 Parse Push[38052:c07] Success!
2012-12-23 01:20:37.933 Parse Push[38052:c07] Final array:

(
)
```

Is there an error with my code, or something that I'm missing?  I am new to interacting with .plists, so I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: what about `NSLog(@"%@",appdata);` ?

Comment: Just edited it to include appdata... @InderKumarRathore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if ([data writeToFile:newPath atomically:YES]) {
```

You are writing again an empty array here

Use this

```
[appdata addObject:appInfo];
NSLog(@"%@",appdata);
if ([appdata writeToFile:newPath atomically:YES]){
```

Comment: Wow!! I can't believe I missed that :) Thanks (will accept your answer as soon as I can!)